# VBA - Simplified copy and paste Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulties simplifying my macros that copies and pastes data into various sheets.

```
'Put the date and time across the top
    Dim rngDT As Range
    Set rngDT = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:B2")
    Worksheets("Data").Range(rngDT, rngDT.End(xlDown)).Copy
    Worksheets("Reporting").Range("C5").Offset((x - 1) * 12, 0).PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

'Copy and transpose the names from the names page
    Worksheets("Point Names").Range("B1:B3").Offset(x, 0).Copy _
    (Worksheets("Reporting").Range("B7").Offset((x - 1) * 12, 0))     

'Copy and transpose the data
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Set dataRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("C1:E1").Offset(1, 3 * x - 3) '.Range("A1:C1")
    Worksheets("Data").Range(dataRng, dataRng.End(xlDown)).Copy
    Worksheets("Reporting").Range("C7").Offset((x - 1) * 12, 0).PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    'Sheets("Data").Select
    'Range("A1").Select
    'ActiveCell.Offset(1, x + 1).Range("A1:C1").Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Selection.Copy
    'Sheets("Reporting").Select
    'Range("C7").Offset((x - 1) * 12, 0).Select
    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
```

Also for reference, it loops `For x = 1 To NumPoints` which `NumPoints = 33` in this example.  Thank you in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is `Selection`?

Comment: @sourceCode obviously the range he selected one line before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code block can be reduced to something like the following:

```
'Put the date and time across the top
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:B2")

Worksheets("Data").Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlDown)).Copy
Worksheets("Reporting").Range("C5").Offset((x - 1) * 12, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

The rest of the code can be reduced in the same way, give it a try.
Always try to avoid using `.Select` or `Selection.` which is bad practice.

> Note that I used `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets` because the `Worksheets` object only contains worksheets but the `Sheets` object also contains worksheets and charts and so on. I recommend *always* to use `Worksheets` over `Sheets` unless you really need `Sheets`, which in most cases you do not.

---

Also make sure that **every** `Range`, `Columns`, `Rows`, `Cells` and so on is prefixed by a valid named worksheet. If not VBA assumes that you meant the `ActiveSheet`. That means:

```
Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlDown)).Copy
```

is exactly the same as

```
ActiveSheet.Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlDown)).Copy
```

But `ActiveSheet` is not a defined sheet. Therefore there might be a chance that the active sheet is the right one, but there is also the chance that it is not. So you get a randomly working/non-working code.

Therefore always use a defined worksheet like

```
Worksheets("Data").Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlDown)).Copy
```

and never let VBA assume the worksheet.

---

Edit to your comment. This would be something like this:

```
Dim dataRng As Range
Set dataRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Offset(1, x + 1).Range("A1:C1")
Worksheets("Data").Range(dataRng, dataRng.End(xlDown)).Copy
Worksheets("Reporting").Range("C7").Offset((x - 1) * 12, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but is the `Worksheets` necessary for `Worksheets("Data").Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlDown)).Copy`

Comment: @ACohen Yes it is! If you omit to name a worksheet for the range then VBA assumes that it is the `ActiveSheet` which might be wrong. See my edit of the answer.

Comment: could you check my edited code.  I am having troubles with the last block of text

Comment: @ACohen See my edit. And you should keep the original code in your question so any other people who find this question helpful can learn from it too.

Comment: Thanks, that works better, however there's something wrong in another part of my code because it is not calculating in the right sheet.  Which I am guessing is due to Macros errors.

Comment: @ACohen I guess you need another question for that issue. We cannot handle multiple questions at once here.